# "Barts and The London NHS Trust" - Is there a standard way to abbreviate it?

Tags: abbreviations

> Barts and The London NHS Trust

Suppose you have a document where you need to reference this trust many times. This includes references in table cells, so it is not a good idea to use the official name due to its length.

Is there a standard way to handle such cases?

Comment: Get up to date! Barts and The London NHS Trust, Newham University Hospital NHS Trust, and Whipps Cross University Hospital NHS Trust were merged in 2012 to form Barts Health NHS Trust. You could mention it first in full, and then just call it 'the trust' or 'Barts', although this might invite confusion with St Bartholomew's Hospital.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, I know about the merging, but it is assumed to find an answer to the problem of abbreviations of complex names in general; that is, _Barts and The London NHS Trust_ is just an example. I like your suggestion to use "Barts", thanks.

Comment: Judicious use of pronouns such as 'it', 'them', 'him', etc, can help with avoiding repetitive runs.

Comment: *it is assumed to find an answer to the problem of abbreviations of complex names in general* There is no "general answer" to the abbreviation of long names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard way, especially in legal documents but possible everywhere.

**Example**

*Barts and The London NHS Trust is a great organisation, I think so anyway, blah blah blag blah. Anyway, as I was saying, **the Trust** does a lot of good in the world. **The Trust** is responsible for …*

In a legal document, it is specifically noted that such an abbreviation will be used. In an ordinary, perhaps, journalistic, article, it is assumed that the reader will know that the Trust, refers to the one that is the main subject.

**Notes**

1. I used bold to emphasise "the Trust". That is not needed in an actual document.
2. Use upper case for Trust, as it is part of the name.

Comment: Capitalisation may be subject to style guidance. From the official 2017 Care Quality Commission report on St Bartholomews Hospital: "Staff had an understanding of safeguarding systems and there was a safeguarding team within the **trust**. We found
deprivation of liberty and mental capacity was assessed in line with **trust** policy and legislation"

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repetition of complex or long items, it is common to use  abbreviations or referencing pronouns, etc. Examination of [existing texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barts_Health_NHS_Trust#Hospitals) related to the topic can be instructive.

> **The Lord High Executioner, Sir Charles Chopper**, gave a speech on Thursday in which **he** said that he was opposed to capital punishment. **He** said
> that decapitation was no deterrent to the type of criminal prepared to
> kill. Furthermore, **the LHE** said, the expense and trouble of purchasing,
> sharpening, and storing axes was a burden on the finances of the state. **Sir
> Charles** said that he would be happy to see his role become 'largely
> ceremonial'.

This practice is sometimes called 'elegant variation', and can be overdone. Modern style guides either suggest avoiding it, or keeping it to a minimum. A famous example is often quoted where 'carrot' was replaced by 'popular orange vegetable'. This sort of thing is a misuse, especially where brevity is being aimed for.

[Elegant variation: the good and the bad](https://www.economist.com/johnson/2012/04/04/elegant-variation-the-good-and-the-bad)